# hacer una resta de una suma total de una columna

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una duda quiero saber si se puede hacer una resta de una suma total de una columna por ejemplo :

Quiero restar una cantidad que ingresa en un input como esta en la captura y mostrar el resultado a un lado de la resta de esa operación y también ir guardando todos esos movimientos como un historial  de todas operaciones que se hicieron

Lo que quiero es saber cómo lo puedo hacer o que debo de investigar para hacer esto que quiero hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  <table class="tabla">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="th">Ventas totales</th>
        <th class="th">Valor a ingresar</th>
        <th class="th">Resultado</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
             $relsult = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(total) AS VentasT FROM ventas");
             $relsult->execute();
            while($row = $relsult->fetch()) {?>
    <tr>
        <td class="td"><?php echo $row['VentasT'] ?></td>
        <?php }?>
        <form action="../procesos/ProcesoMovimientos.php" method="post">
            <td class="posicionth centrar">
                <span id="letra"> $ </span>
                <input type="text" name='valor' class="inputcolor tamaInput" name="" id="inputventa" require
                    placeholder="Ingrese la cantidad" autocomplete="off">
                <button type="submit" id="añadir" class="btn btn-color ">Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Intente con algo asi se que esta mal pero quiero saber como lo puedo acomodar como se debe

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $resta=$_POST['valor'];

    $relsult = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(total) AS (VentasT-$resta) as Total  FROM ventas");

    $relsult->execute();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizá para este caso lo mas conveniente sea tener una nueva tabla con el historial o transacciones

```
Transacciones{ id, fecha, cantidad, motivo, etc.. }
```

Cada vez que alguien haga una transacción creas un registro (`INSERT INTO Transacciones VALUES ( .... )`)

Y a la hora de mostrar los datos haces 2 queries. Una con todas las transacciones y la otra con lo que sea que "Ventas" signifique.

De esa forma puedes mostrar la tabla de todos los movimientos y a la vez calcular la resta que pides.

PD: Si hay varios tipos de "Ventas" en la tabla Transacciones quizás quieras un id compuesto entre el id de Ventas y un auto incremental en Transacciones

Comment: mmmm mas o menos lo que debería de hacer es unir mi tabla actual que contiene las el total de ventas que la saco con SUM y hacer otra tabla que contenga el valor ingresado el cual se le va a restar ala otra tabla de la suma ?

Comment: Depende. la verdad que no entiendo al 100% tu caso, así que quizá sería buena idea editar la pregunta y explicarlo mejor. Si ya tienes una tabla con todas las operaciones de donde sacas el sum, puedes hacer 2 consultas una para sacar el sum y otra para sacar las operaciones.